# How to remove the tape from the folded state?

Tags: animation

I am creating an animation to peel off the tape.

I would like to make it so that the tape peels off straight from the folded state, without bending, as in the attached image. (Sorry for my bad drawing).

I found a way to peel off while bent on YouTube, but I couldn't find a way to peel off straight from the bent state, so I asked a question.

[image]
I tried using Follow path, but it moves the part I don't want to move.

Thank you.

Comment: A Curve modifier seems to work fine, see: https://zupimages.net/up/22/05/25ca.gif

Comment: Really!
That's exactly the kind of animation I wanted to make!

However, I couldn't tell what it was moving in the GIF you sent me.
Is it empty or something?

I added a Curve Modifire to the Tape and selected a curve, but I don't know what the process is after that.
I'm sorry for my ignorance, but can you please tell me the rest of the story?

Comment: Lattice is another option

Comment: I tried to use Lattice and Shape keys, but it didn't work.

But Mr. moonboots' method solved it successfully.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a curve, flatten it on Y, press <kbd>V</kbd> to convert the handles to *Vector*:

[image]

Extrude to give it the shape you want:

[image]

Create a plane, subdivide it, in *Object* mode put it at the same position as the curve:

[image]

Give your plane a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*, when you move the curve, here is what happens:

[image]

Comment: I had to manually faltter the distorted Bezier curve every time. Thank you very much for your kindness.

Also, you were moving the curve itself, which makes sense.
Once again, thank you very much Mr.moonboots